# Reactjs send data through pages and components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page called: **List.js** which renders the component: **Box** for every item on the **List** page. My List.js also consists of a component called: **MainSpace**. Now every **Box** component will consists of a `button` with an `onClick` function. Depending on which **Box** component you click, I want to fill the **MainSpace** with data coming from that specific **Box** component, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```
render() {

   for (let index in data) {
      list.push(
        <Box data={data[index]}/>
      );
   }
   return (
   <div>
    {list}
    <MainSpace>

   </div>
   );
}
```

Now the Box component looks something like this:

```
class Box extends Component {
fillMainSpace(){
//Send this.prop.data to the list.js file and fill the MainSpace component from there I think?
}

render(){
   return (
   <div>
       <span>{this.props.data.text}</span>
       <button onClick={this.fillMainSpace}></button>
   </div>
   );
}
}
```

**Mainspace** doesn't have much. I just want to load for example the `this.props.data.image` from the clicked button from the **Box** component. Even `console.log(this.props.data);` would be sufficient. Calling the `<MainSpace>` component in every `<Box>` component is not an option, since that would render a lot of unnecessary extra components.

So my question being:

How would I be able to access the `this.props.data` of the clicked button of a `<Box>` component and use it in my `<MainSpace>` component?

**EDIT:**
Adding the MainSpace Component:

```
class MainSpace extends Component {

render(){
    return (
     <div>
     {this.props.data.image}
     </div>
    );
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save selected item in state like `selectedItem` and then pass that data to MainSpace

```js
const List = props => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(props.data[0]);
  const onSelect = item => {
    setSelectedItem(item);
  };
  return (
     <div calssName="list">
     {props.data.map(item => <Box data={item} onSelect={onSelect} />)}
     <MainSpace data={selectedItem} />
   }
}

const Box = props => {
   const { data, onSelect } = props;
   return (
     <div>
        <span>{data.someKey}</span>
        <button onClick={() => onSelect(data)} >Select</button>
     </div>
   );
};
```

Using class components

```js
class Box extends Component {
  fillMainSpace = () => {
    const { onSelect, data } = this.props;
    onSelect(data);
  }

  render(){
     const { data } = this.props;
     return (
     <div>
         <span>{data.text}</span>
         <button onClick={this.fillMainSpace} }></button>
     </div>
     );
  }
}

class List extends React.Component {

  state = { selectedItem: this.props.data[0] };
  
  onSelect = item => {
     this.setState({ selectedItem: item });
  }
  render() {
     const { data } = this.props;
     const { selectedItem } = this.state;
     const list = data.map(item =>  <Box data={item} onSelect={this.onSelect} />);
     return (
       <div>
        {list}
        <MainSpace data={selectedItem}>
       </div>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to ReactJS and I want to note that `list.js`, `Box` and `MainSpace` are all in seperate files. How would I pass data then or would it change nothing?

Comment: Ok, I thought you would get the idea. Can you kindly share complete component class without unnecessary methods just those are enough to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean? Theres not anything else extra really in those components. Box literally consists of text and a button and mainspace is just a div with text that should change based on a click

Comment: Your for loop is outside the render function. How are you doing this?

Comment: Sorry thats my mistake. The for loop is in the render. My bad I just typed the important parts manually and put the for loop in the wrong place in my question. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Loko Have a look at the second part of answer. I hope you will get this now

Comment: When I do `console.log(this.props.data)` in the `MainSpace` component, I get Undefined with the second part of your answer

Comment: Im already getting `undefined` at `onSelect = item => {
     this.setState({ selectedItem: item });
  }`

When trying to console.log the selectedItem

Comment: You are not passing data from child to parent in `onSelect(data)` callback

Comment: `fillMainSpace = () => {
    const { onSelect, data } = this.props;
}` when I console.log(data) I get:  undefined as well and when I console.log(onSelect). I get: `(item) {
      _this.setState({
        selectedItem: item
      });
    }`

Sorry but I dont understand whats going on

Comment: This means that you are not passing `data` prop to your `Box` components

Comment: Sorry you were right. I had a typo in one of the variables. Your example is working now. Thanks!